# Two physical servers with sql server on same network

Tags: sql-server, network, windows-server

IS there a way I can remotely access sql server DB having two different servers in the same network/public IP?

The first Server is configured to listen to 1433 port but we make the connections using No-Ip provider.

As both servers will be under the same DNS, how can I configure my app/sql server to connect to the DB in the second server?

Comment: The question is a little unclear - do you have two separate servers running a SQL Server instance or a single server running multiple SQL Server instances?

Comment: Sorry about late response. Two servers, two different instances

Comment: Okay, so you want to access databases on Server #2 from queries on Server #1, is that what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Not exactly. In the company I work for they unnecessarily bought a second server. So in order to put it to use, we'll split our clients's databases into both of them according to the type of application. I had to change SQL port then, because both servers was under the same external IP

Answer (score 0):

Solved that by changing SQL port on SQL Server Configuration Manager, but you'll always have to specify the port for every connections that is different from the standard 1433 port. If you have an APP, you'll also have to change the connection string method to set up a different port or work the code to get it from an external file.

Comment: Changing the port is not an answer to your question. There are two different SQL Servers on two separate machines. Both machines can use the same SQL Server port, because they each have a different computer name.